# Convert simple text column data into single line with powershell

Tags: powershell, rows

i have simple txt file with enumerated drives like this

```
C:\
X:\
Y:\
Z:\
```

and i need an output of this but in one line with one space in between, like

```
C:\ X:\ Y:\ Z:\
```

been searching and trying but nada.
thank you

Comment: sorry, i didn't get this ... what's with the ` ?

Comment: Check out the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
((get-content SimpleTxtFile.txt) -join "`t").Replace("`t", " ")
```

I am using the `-join` operator to join all the enumerated drives separated by a `tab`. Then used the `Replace` method to replace the tab with a single space.

See [about_special_characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-6).

See PowerShell [Replace method](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html).

**OR**

As suggested by @Boxdog in the comment you can simply do this -

```
(get-content SimpleTxtFile.txt) -join " ")
```

Comment: No need for the `.Replace()`.  You can simply use: `(get-content SimpleTxtFile.txt) -join " "`

Comment: @boxdog - Yeah even simpler. Good tip.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for bothering with such simple things.